# How to create unique combination of sql server database columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, unique, unique-constraint

I'm trying to create relationships table which connects users.

I have the following structure:

```
1. id
2. fromuserid
3. touserid
4. state (none, send, accepted, rejected)
```

I want to have constraint that any pair from/to should be unique. I mean there shouldn't be an entry like

```
1, **123,124**, send 
2, **124,123**, send
```

First of all I created constraint that from != to. It works perfect:

```
CONSTRAINT [CK__FromUserId_ToUserId] CHECK (FromUserId != ToUserId),
```

Then I tried to create unique index, constraint etc, nothing helped.

```
CONSTRAINT [CK_FromUserId_ToUserId_Combination] UNIQUE (FromUserId, ToUserId)
```

or

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_FromUserId_ToUserId_Combination] 
  ON USERLINKS (FromUserId, ToUserId)
```

Both works fine to reject records like:

```
1, 123,124,send 
2, 123,124,send
```

But none works to reject records like:

```
1, 123,124,send 
2, 124,123,send
```

Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with computed columns.  Add the "leastId" and "greatestId" columns and then create the index on them:

```
alter table relationships
    add leastId as (case when fromuserid < touserid then fromuserid else touserid end);

alter table relationships
    add greatestId as (case when fromuserid < touserid then touserid else fromuserid end);

create unique index relatinonships_leastId_greastestId_Combination
    on relationships(leastId, greatestId, combination);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use "INSTEAD OF INSERT Triggers"

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175089(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: While your link might technically answer the question, it would be preferable if you could paraphrase the essential parts of the answer in your own words here. That way, the information will be right here, and will remain available even if the linked page is moved some day.